# Analytic continuation of a square root

Tags: complex-analysis

I did not understand quite well the concept of analytic continuation.
Given the function $f(z)=\sqrt{z^2+9}$, in a small neighborhood of the point $z=4$, the function has a germ such that $f(4)=5$.
How can one describe the result of its analytical continuation along paths from 4 to -4?

For example,

(a) $|z|=4$, $Imz \geq 0$;

(b) the line segment joining 4 to -4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if you find some analytic function $\overline{f}$ on an open set $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ containing the path in question, such that $\overline{f} = f$ on a small neighbourhood of $z = 4$, then $\overline{f}$ must be the analytic continuation of $f$ along that path.

We generally can define an analytic square root with an explicit formula given a simply connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ which does not contain any branching point. In this case branching points are the places where $z^2 + 9 = 0$, i.e. $z = \pm 3 i$. Both paths omit that point, so it's relatively easy to find a simply connected open set containing the path and not containing these points, then figure out the formula.